# abp bearer token fails with These requirements were not met: DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user

Tags: c#, .net-core, abp

I am using abp framework version 5.2. I want some 3rd party application to access the API and is trying to implment the jwtbearer token based on [1](https://community.abp.io/posts/consume-an-abp-framework-api-from-a-.net-core-console-application-5b8o2lrw). Iam able to retrieve the token but when it is used to access the API, i am getting login html page as response. Then i added the below code

```
` context.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
  {
      // Forward any requests that start with /api to the JWT scheme.
      options.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx =>
      {
         return ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") ? JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme : null;
      };
  });` .
```

Now i am getting unauthorized error and the log is having the information These requirements were not met: DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user. I am not sure if i am missing anything.